# Why do I see the node ID on the menu URL instead of the path alias?

Tags: nodes, navigation

I created different menus and need them to be displayed in a node based on the language currently visited for a specific node type.

Via my theme.theme, I added the following code to retrieve the menus:

```
if($lang == 'pt') {
   $recipe_block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('recipespt');
   $variables['recipe_menu_block_view'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block')->view($recipe_block);            
 } elseif($lang == 'es') {
   $recipe_block = \Drupal\block\Entity\Block::load('recipeses');
   $variables['recipe_menu_block_view'] = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('block')->view($recipe_block);     
 }
```

Then I went into the node template and pulled the menus:

```
{% if content.field_product_type['0']['#context']['value'] == 'Recipe' %}
  {{recipe_menu_block_view}}
{% else %}
  {{cocktail_menu_block_view}}
{% endif %}
```

When I visit the main site(English) the menu links look ok.

But when I switch language and hover over the menu, instead of seeing the URL alias I am seeing the node id.

How can I pull the menu through the .theme and see the node alias instead of the node alias?

Comment: Does the linked page definitely have an ES translation? As no translation = no alias

Comment: Yes..at this point all the pages are translated